# Current views about whether it’s appropriate to refer to God as "It"?

Tags: names-of-god, gender, political-correctness

I have recently read in a book about some debate around the fact that God is considered a masculine figure (He/His) and that we should find gender neutral of expressing the same ideas.

In my native language it is very hard to do this (God is a masculine noun and it is also derived from Domine Deus which also sounds masculine).

However, English has the advantage of having "it". According to [Wordnick](https://www.wordnik.com/words/it), "it" usage guide is also:

> Used of a **nonhuman entity**; an animate being whose sex is unspecified (..)

It sounds like a good fit, but I am wondering if this is ever appropriate or even offensive.

**Questions:** What are some of the mainstream theological views on this? Secondly, what about the Biblical basis for doing so, is it *specifically* forbidden? Do any denominations do this in practice?

Comment: @Al Brown Unless you know within reasonable assurance that your edit is in line with the OP’s thought, the post should not be altered as such! Making this a question to a denominational-survey question invalidates already existing answers!

Comment: @ken I don't think there's anything wrong with invalidating existing answers on a closed question.  That seemed like a good edit IMO; we should ask the community.

Comment: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3911/if-a-question-is-closed-are-we-allowed-to-edit-the-question-in-such-a-way-that

Comment: I used my approve edit as an author of the post because it is a clear improvement over my initial version. I have it meets the community standards so that it gets reopened.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In English, the appropriate non-gender pronouns are 'they' and 'them', but this construction is clumsy if people attempt to use it all the time. It simply does not work as a substitute. It does not adequately express person.

Babies are sometimes referred to as 'it' because, I suppose, their personality is not yet apparent. But, no, it is not appropriate in English (and, yes, it is offensive) to call a person 'it'. English just does not work like that.

When a voice was heard from heaven saying :

> This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased; hear ye him. [Matthew 17:5 KJV] ουτος εστιν ο υιος μου ο αγαπητος εν ω ευδοκησα αυτου ακουετε

the voice used the masculine gender pronoun, αυτου - 'him'.

I think that should be respected. Throughout the Hebrew and Greek scripture - God's revelation of himself - the masculine pronoun is used.

Comment: It's not at all clumsy... just ask the trans community. Works pretty well for all the non-binaries who identify with it.

Comment: I'm not sure babies are ever referred to as "it" beyond the initial announcement of "It's a [gender]!".

Comment: @Adonalsium The subject is dealt with in detail on a highly up-voted question  and answer on [Stack Exchange - English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their). I would not want to comment further than that question and answer.

Comment: I'm old enough to remember when the non-gender (singular) pronouns were "he" and "him". ("They" and "them" were plural, which was not gendered.)  That is to say that when referring to a person of unknown/unspecified gender, the "masculine" pronouns were used.  Thus, when "she" and "her" were used, it was in reference to someone explicitly known to be female.  This is no longer the case. But it was the case when nearly all English translations were done.

Comment: @MontyHarder, You're really 700 years old?  The use of singular "they" dates back to about the 14th century, and was used by such notable authors as Shakespeare.

Comment: @Mark Monty is not saying that "they" was never used: just that it wasn't the popular solution.  Generally it was (as in most translations of the Bible still) that "he" was used to mean either "he" or "she" in general cases.  ("My Brothers" probably doesn't exclude sisters.)

Comment: @Cullub : and even now it isn't, it's just a very load minority who wants to rewrite grammar every decade or so, and pretend that it's some kind of law.

Comment: @Mark None of my English Grammar teachers agreed with Shakespeare on that point.  I was explicitly taught that when speaking of an individual of unknown gender to use "he", "him", "his", and that referring to an individual as "they" was substandard usage.  In fact, if the person in question was overweight and sensitive about it, it could be considered downright insulting to refer to "them".

Comment: I actually learned that **both** “they” and “he” were grammatically incorrect for a single person of unknown sex.

Comment: @AlBrown One could spend hours wandering around the various arguments about pronouns and gender ---------> [Stack Exchange English Language & Usage - pronoun plural gender](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149762/259840).

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/63532/43095 Probably not very popular but Im starting to think an honest take can only go this way.

Comment: +1 Just had to make your post 25 or more.

Comment: @KenGraham Thank you kindly.

Comment: "the appropriate non-gender pronouns are 'they' and 'them'" Why is this appropriate? The standard Trinitarian conception of God is 3 persons but they are united in a way that is different from when we use the word 'they'. God is more like a team, for which we would use 'it', but 'they' when specifically referring to the persons within that team. No?

Answer (score 12):

We should refer to God in the manner God wants us to refer to God (not using a pronoun here intentionally).

The first time we see a pronoun for God is in Genesis 1:5 (NASB)

> 1:5 God called the light day, and the darkness **He** called night and there was evening and there was morning, one day.

Now one might say that this is how Moses (considered the author of Genesis) referred to God.

So we can look at how each Person of the Trinity referred to the other. Let's refer to them as the 1st, 2nd and 3rd persons of the Trinity.

1st Person sends a message about 2nd Person through an angel to Joseph:

> Matthew 1:21 "She will bear a **Son**; and you shall call **His** name Jesus,
>           for **He** will save His people from their sins." (NASB)

2nd Person (named Jesus) speaks about the 1st Person as "Father":

> Matthew 5:45 so that you may be sons of your **Father** who is in heaven; for **He** causes His sun to rise on the evil and the good, and sends rain on the righteous and the unrighteous.

2nd Person speaks about the 3rd Person (Holy Spirit - see below) and refers to "He" and "Him":

> John 14:26 "But the Helper, the ***Holy Spirit***, whom the Father will send
>           in My name, **He** will teach you all things, and bring to your
>           remembrance all that I said to you.(NASB)

Further, per the complete revelation of the Bible, Christ will come back for wedding His corporate bride (Rev 19:7). And **He** is the bridegroom (John 3:29).

Comment: The Greek for John 14:16, 17 uses the neuter gender for the pronouns referring to the holy spirit, not masculine pronouns. This is because the Greek word for "spirit" is of the neuter gender. However, in verse 26, it does use a masculine pronoun, because the Greek word for "helper" is a masculine noun.

Comment: @4castle: Thanks for your comment. What about `Helper` mentioned in verse 16? It seems to be Masculine too.

Comment: @4castle: "...that **He** may be with you forever". The "He" refers to the Holy Spirit. Unlike Jesus who was with them for only a few years, the "Holy Spirit" would be with the forever.

Answer (score 5):

This is as much a theological as a linguistic question, not least a question of other languages than English — in particular Hebrew — and their translation.

Canonical English as well as canonical Christianity unequivocally assign a male gender to the Jewish/Christian god. On the other hand, if you are looking for answers beyond the canon, all bets are off: How we speak and what we believe is ultimately our own decision. By the way, the linguistic question is quite interesting, not least because Hebrew does not have a neuter and one of the words used for God, *Elohim*, is plural.

You also may find [an article](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/13/opinion/is-god-transgender.html) in the New York Times by Rabbi Mark Sameth interesting. He argued that there is more gender fluidity to God than one might think.

Comment: Agreed. What's more the Hebrew holy Name introduced in Genesis 2 is a form of the first-person singular indicative of the verb *to be.* That Name is rendered Lord with small caps in English translation, and observant Jews avoid speaking it. There's no gender-revealing inflection on it. In John's Gospel Jesus sometimes speaks the words ἐγώ εἰμι, rendered into English as "I am he," but close in meaning to the Name.  Humility is a good start when we try to fit the holy One into human categories. Can we live with the mystery of the holy nature?

Comment: @O.Jones Regarding ἐγώ εἰμι: If we think that Jesus indeed said that, it is probably already a translation -- I assume Jesus (usually) spoke Hebrew?

Comment: @O.Jones Actually Jesus' mother tongue appears to have been Aramaic, if we can believe [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_of_Jesus); but the article suggest that he also spoke some Greek and Hebrew, so it could conceivably be a literal quote.

Answer (score 3):

No, “It” is inappropriate because God neither inanimate nor an animal.

One fairly common practice is to avoid using the pronoun altogether. As a matter of style, it takes a lot of thought to pull this off well, but it doesn't necessarily require awkward English. You can do a lot with strategic passives, controlling your sentence structure, etc. A mild consequence is that sentences come across as awkwardly emphatic. “God will accomplish God's purposes.” The alternative to the reflexive pronoun is “Godself,” like “God can speak for Godself.” That's a neologism, and therefore could serve as an intention way to communicate one's position on the matter.

It is a reasonable question, but obviously a politically charged one, whether using a masculine pronoun for God meaningfully affects people's perceptions of God. People differ as well in their perceptions of English style, so it is good to be charitable in assessing other people's writing. (On a separate gender issue, I prefer to use a generic feminine, or to alternate between masculine and feminine, rather than use singular “their.”)

Comment: Do you think it's inappropriate to use 'it' to refer to a family or team? Those are neither inanimate or animals.

Comment: I would refer to families and teams with plural pronouns. “The Patriots are playing tonight; they're expected to win.” “The Jones are coming to dinner; they're bringing a salad.”

Comment: Thanks for this - do you think it's inappropriate, though? There are many cases in typical English usage where 'it' is used for a family. "My family has 8 people. It's big." and so on.

Comment: That's kind of a borderline case for me... It might be okay, but I'd prefer to say, “My family is big; there are eight people.”